# Moving Envelope is Leaving Original

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to move an envelope that is sitting in my Inbox to FolderX. When I execute the following I do see the envelope in question is now in FolderX but I still see it in my Inbox.  Is this by design?  My expectation is that I would no longer see the envelope in the Inbox folder.

Thanks,

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/244043/folders/966ec83d-8b35-4ae4-b5e6-84ae06ca5ab0 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
X-DocuSign-Authentication: ...
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 73
Expect: 100-continue

{
"envelopeIds": [
 "f2da7a3e-16fa-44e9-ad1c-903efd70ecb4"]
}
```

Comment: Because you're the sender and recipient, it moved it from your Sent items to your new folder.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew states, if you are the sender and the recipient of the envelope then it will still show in your Inbox as well as the new `FolderX` that you moved it to.